# How to show and hide a loading .gif image when using jQuerys .change()

Tags: jquery

How can I show and hide a loding.gif image when using the code below? That's all the code there is. There's no `beforeSend:` or `success:` here.

```
$("#seg").change(function(){
$("#sSeg").load("/blah/blah.php?option="+$("#seg").val());
});
```

What happens here is, when a drop downs value changes it'll fetch new content for another drop down list. I wanted to add a loading.gif there so the user knows things are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a div like this where you want to show the loading image and put a loading image inside it and set it's display as none by default and show it using jQuery.

<div id="loading"><img src="loading.gif"></div>

```
$("#seg").change(function(){
    $("#loading").css("display","block");
    $("#sSeg").load("/blah/blah.php?option="+$("#seg").val(),function(){ 
       $("#loading").css("display","none");
    });
});
```

Comment: That will show and then instantly hide the loading div.  `load()` is not a synchronous function.

Answer (score 3):

You can show the loading before using `load` and then hide it in `load's` callback function

```
$("#seg").change(function() {
    $('img.loading').show();
    $("#sSeg").load("/blah/blah.php?option="+$("#seg").val(), function() {
        $('img.loading').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your above example, the simplest way is to show the loading.gif and have it replaced with the dropdown by the load function...

```
$("#seg").change(function(){
    $("#sSeg").html("<img src=\"loading.gif\" />");
    $("#sSeg").load("/blah/blah.php?option="+$("#seg").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your `.change()` function  is your `beforeSend:` and .load has a callback function that is called when it is finished. this should work:

```
$("#seg").change(function(){
    $('#gif').show();
    $("#sSeg").load("/blah/blah.php?option="+$("#seg").val(), function() {
        $('#gif').hide();
    });
});
```

see the [.load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).